# 固定IPアドレスの設定について

Tags: linux, network, vmware

質問させてください。

VMware Workstation上のESXi上に構築した仮想マシンの固定IPアドレスの設定方法についてお聞きしたいです。

自宅のネットワーク環境はポケットWifiかスマホのテザリングで、特に設定などしていないため当然DHCPの状態です。
そこで、先述の環境上にあるLinuxマシンに固定IPを設定したい場合、どこから手を付けるべきでしょうか。
然るべきネットワークの設定手順だけ知ることができれば、OS側のファイル設定等は自分で調べようと思います。
質問点を要約しますと、

1. Wifiやスマホ側で何らかの設定が必要でしょうか。あるとすれば機器により設定が異なると思いますので、まずは自分で調べてみようと思います。
2. ESXiに固定IPを振らなければ、その上の仮想マシンではIPを固定することはできませんか。因みにESXiは1台使いで、特に複数台構築する予定はありません。
3. Wifiとスマホのテザリングは当然ネットワーク部が異なりますが、仮にどちらかでIPを固定しても接続先を変えればやはりIPを固定しなおさないといけませんか。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問者さんのおっしゃる「固定IPアドレス」とは何のことで、どのような目的でその「固定IPアドレスの設定」を必要とされているのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。固定IPアドレスとはサーバ起動時に都度振り当てられて変わってしまうことのないIPアドレスという定義で使いました。目的としましては、複数台の仮想マシンを管理する際にDNSやLDAPの設定ファイルをIPアドレスが変わる度に全台都度書き換えるのはバカらしい…というところから、各サーバで使用するIPアドレスを不変的な状態に固定しまえないかという考えです。

Comment: ただ単に固定IPを振りたいだけなら、DHCPの環境であろうとクライアント側で任意の (DHCPで配っている範囲の) IPアドレスを設定するだけだと思います。 /  質問本文では「1台使いで、複数台構築する予定はない」と言ってますが、コメント欄では「複数台の仮想マシンを管理」で話が矛盾しているように見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。1台というのはESXiのことを指しておりまして、その上には複数台の仮想マシンを構築している状態でございます。一見してわかりにくい記述があり申し訳ございませんでした。ありがとうございます。私自身、IPを固定するということが今ひとつ理解も体感も及んでいない状態ですので、まずは任意のIPアドレスを振る設定を試してみて、そこでうまくいかなくなることがあればまた具体的に質問できるようになるかと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずはそのポケットWifiのDHCPの設定を見て、割当開始アドレスと、割当最大数から、そのネットワーク上でDHCPの配布外で通信可能なアドレスを割り出します
そのうえで、LinuxのIP設定で、そのアドレスを設定します
注意すべきは、DHCPを使わない設定となるので、デフォルトゲートウェイやサブネットマスクの設定、DNS設定などをすべて手動で行う必要があります